# Realm Object is not part of the schema for this Realm

Tags: java, android, gradle, realm, illegalargumentexception

I'm using realm as database for my app and i have model `SessionModel`:

```
public class SessionModel extends RealmObject {

    private long id;

    private int currentPomod;

    private int state;

    ...getters\setters
}
```

When i'm trying to create new document in database:

```
Realm.init(this);

realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(defSession);
```

**I got this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SessionModel is not part of the schema for this Realm`**

My top level gradle file contains this dependencies:

```
...
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.3.0"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
...
```

and app gradle module applying this plugins (ont top of build.gradle module app file):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

...
```

Instant Run disabled.

Comment: do you use Kotlin, or any other magical thing, maybe `apt` or `kapt`? Supposedly `annotationProcessor` scope should be automatically applied if you don't have `android-apt`.

Comment: I don't use these features.

Comment: Problem solved. Realm not working with Jack toolchain enabled in gradle. So when i removed Jack from my app Realm works properly. Also i've added Retrolambda lib instead of Jack for lambda expressions support.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the following situation: `MyClass` was implementing `RealmModel`, but was not annotated with `@RealmClass`

Answer (score 0):

Found some solution from [git issues](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3817#issuecomment-261696048). Its looking like same problem you have.

**Solution:**
**`apply apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' before apply plugin: 'realm-android'`**

Hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this error just now. I tried rearranging my plugins still didnt work. Turns out since I am using a managed realmList now for automatic update, I have to change the realm config as well on the application. just delete your current realm. using this
Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);  then start again but just comment the code out.